# Select values based on conditions

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data set:

```
 id pnum t1 t2 t3 w1 w2 w3 
  1    1  w  r  r  1  1  1  
  1    2  o  o  w  0  0  1  
  1    3  o  w  w  1  1  1    
  2    1  o  w  t  1  0  1   
  2    2  s  s  s  1  0  1    
  2    3  s  s  s  1  0  1
```

`Id` defines the group membership.

Based on `id` and pnum I would like to identify the `common` measurements reported with `pnum 3` at time `t` with respect to `w`.

In other words `id` and `pnum` define different individuals who took some measurements. In some cases the measurement was taken together in other cases the measurement was taken alone. If taken together than at `'w'` we have value `1`.

```
For example: 

Common activities at time t:
```

`Id 1` `pnum 1` at `t1` reported (eg. `1`) that a measurement was taken with from the group, more specifically with `id1/pnum3`. If the measurement data taken together is common in both groups I would like to save it.

```
Uncommon  activities at time t:
```

`Id 2` `pnum 1` at t1 reported (eg. 1) that a measurement was taken with from the group, more specifically with `id2/pnum2` and `pnum 3.` In this case the measurement data taken together is uncommon between `id2/pnum1` and `pnum 2` as well between `id2/pnum1` and `pnum 3`. I don't want to save these measurements. But, I would like to save the common one reported between `id2/pnum2` and `pnum 3.`

```
Generic example id 1:
```

In the group with id 1 pnum1 and pnum3 at t1 took together a measurement. `Pnum 1` reported `w`, `pnum 2` and `pnum 3` reported `o`. This means that `pnum 2` and `pnum 3` reported the same measurement. However, when I look at w1 I could observe that they were not together when they did as at `w1` `pnum 2` is `0` and `pnum 3` is `1`. In other words, even though the measurement are common for `pnum 2` and `pnum 3` as they were not taken together I don't want to save the case. I would need to report if they reported the same measurements or not. In this case pnum1 reported `w` while `pnum 3` reported `o`, so the measurements don't match. Therefore I coded `0`. I don't want to save the case.

I would like to identify the common measurements that were taken together at time t.

Output:

```
 id pnum t1   t2   t3  
  1    1  0   0    0                       
  1    2  0   0    w                    
  1    3  0   s    w                       
  2    1  0   0    0                       
  2    2  s   0    s                       
  2    3  s   0    s
```

Sample data:

```
 df<-structure(list(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),pnum=c(1,2,3,1,2,3), t1=c("w","o","o","o","s","s"), t2=c("r","o","w","w","s","s"),t3 = c("r","w","w","t","s","s"), w1= c(1,0,1,1,1,1), w2 = c(1,0,1,0,0,0), w3 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @Ronak thanks . basically t1..t3 are fixed they do not change. So for example at t1 all 3 individuals took some measures. Pnum 1 reported w, pnum 2 and pnum 3 reported o. This means that pnum 2 and pnum3 reported the same measurement. However, when I look at w1 I could observe that they were not together when they did as at w1 pnum 2 is 0 and pnum3 is 1. In other words, even though the measurement are common for pnum 2 and pnum3 as they were not taken together I don't want to save the case. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @jay.sf thanks created 2 separate data frames one for t1..t3 and one for w1..w3. Than I merged the two based on index and pnum and I set a condition using ifelse function.

Comment: My question implied that you might want to show the code.

Comment: @jay.sf thanks I will adopt the code to this example and post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get why in your expected output there is an "s" at `[id1, pnum3, t2]` - other than that, I think the following might help you:

First of all, pivoting your data to a "longer" format, where you can group by time, helps you to generalize your code.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_longer <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = matches("^[tw]\\d+$"),
    names_to = c(".value","time"),
    names_pattern = "([tw])(\\d+)"
  )
```

The above pivots your data to look like this:

```
> head(df_longer)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
     id  pnum time  t         w
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1     1     1 1     w         1
2     1     1 2     r         1
3     1     1 3     r         1
4     1     2 1     o         0
5     1     2 2     o         0
6     1     2 3     w         1
```

Now, you can easily group it up and identify those individuals that have given common answers at any given time:

```
common_answers <- df_longer %>%
  arrange(id, time, pnum) %>%
  filter(w == 1) %>% # throw out if the answer was given individually
  select(-w) %>%  # w not needed anymore
  group_by(id, time, t) %>% # group by selected answer
  filter(n() > 1) %>% # keep only answers given >1 times
  ungroup()
```

This presents you with only only a filtered set of your data where answers were given commonly in group:

```
> common_answers
# A tibble: 6 x 4
     id  pnum time  t    
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     1     2 3     w    
2     1     3 3     w    
3     2     2 1     s    
4     2     3 1     s    
5     2     2 3     s    
6     2     3 3     s
```

---

// ADDITION:
In case you have to rely on the "wide" format in your output, you can obviously retain all data, modify `t` so that it only retains its value when it is given commonly by >1 subject and then widen your df again:

```
common_answers_wide <- df_longer %>%
  group_by(id, time, w, t) %>%
  mutate(
    # retain t only when the response has been given by >1 subject
    t = case_when(
      w == 0 ~ "0",
      n() > 1 ~ t,
      T ~ "0"
    )
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-w) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = time, names_prefix = "t", names_sort = T,
    values_from = t
  )
```

That gives you exactly the desired output:

```
> common_answers_wide
# A tibble: 6 x 5
     id  pnum t1    t2    t3   
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1     1 0     0     0    
2     1     2 0     0     w    
3     1     3 0     0     w    
4     2     1 0     0     0    
5     2     2 s     0     s    
6     2     3 s     0     s
```

Comment: @Rstudent was it necessary for you to retain the "wide" format you showed in your expected outcome example? (I'll add a way in how to get to that as well, just for good measure)